# how to change multiple combobox ListFillRange to a named range based on a cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to create multiple drop down lists that changes based on which list they want to use. 
For example, if they changed the control cell to "List 1", all comboboxes (ActiveX) would change their listfillrange to "=List 1". And if the control cell is changed to "List 2", all comboboxes would update their listfillrange to "=List 2". There's a way to do this with Data Validation but I need the ComboBox function of being able to type and the dropdown would change to show the items in the list beginning with the string that was typed.

I'm a complete beginner with VBA so I do not completely understand nuances compared to languages. I feel that I am missing a lot of proper syntax. I've mashed together some code from searches but none match exactly what I'm looking for so I tried to alter it in some way. I think I butchered a lot of it. I'm so sorry aha

```
Dim i As Integer

Private Sub ListChange()
    If Range("B4").Value = "Bonnie" Then
        For i = 1 To 182
'            'Iterate from ComboBox1 to ComboBox182 to change
'            listfillrange to 'Bonnie' named range
            Set cb = Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
            cb.ListFillRange = "=Bonnie"
            Next i
    ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "Christina" Then
        For i = 1 To 182
'            Iterate from ComboBox1 to ComboBox182 to change
'            listfillrange to 'Christina' named range
            Set cb = Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
            cb.ListFillRange = "=Christina"
            Next i
    Else:
        For i = 1 To 182
'            Iterate from ComboBox1 to ComboBox182 to change
'            listfillrange to 'Dianne' named range
            Set cb = Sheet1.Shapes("ComboBox" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object
            ComboBox.ListFillRange = "=Dianne"
            Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Also I mentioned that I like using ActiveX ComboBoxes because they show the dropdown dynamically changing as you type the string but I've only been able to make the combobox automatically show the dropdown by having

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.DropDown
End Sub
```

Is there a way to shorten this or would I have to repeat this for 182 ComboBoxes.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that instead of inserting 182 ComboBoxes on the sheet, you should go for one floating Combobox and then you will need only one change event and one ListFillRange code. This floating combobox should appear once you select the target cell.